# Getting all characters ahead of first appearance of special character in R

Tags: r, string, split

I want to get all characters that are ahead of the first "." if there is one. Otherwise, I want to get back the same character ("8" -> "8").

Example:

```
v<-c("7.7.4","8","12.6","11.5.2.1")
```

I want to get something like this:

```
[1] "7 "8" "12" "11"
```

My idea was to split each element at "." and then only take the first split. I found no solution that worked...

Comment: @rawr why not just `numeric_version(v)[,1]`

Comment: @Jota cause i was trying to figure out hidden list and `numeric_version(v)[[1]]` and `numeric_version(v)[[1]][[1]]` and `numeric_version(v)[[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]][[1]]` and getting too far down the rabbit hole

Comment: @rawr you should go ahead and post it as an answer.  I'd never seen that function, and it is quite nice for the example given.

Comment: It would be `unlist(numeric_version(v)[,1])`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `sub`

```
sub("\\..*", "", v)
#[1] "7"  "8"  "12" "11"
```

or a few `stringi` options:

```
library(stringi)
stri_replace_first_regex(v, "\\..*", "")
#[1] "7"  "8"  "12" "11"
# extract vs. replace
stri_extract_first_regex(v, "[^\\.]+")
#[1] "7"  "8"  "12" "11"
```

If you want to use a splitting approach, these will work:

```
unlist(strsplit(v, "\\..*"))
#[1] "7"  "8"  "12" "11"

# stringi option
unlist(stri_split_regex(v, "\\..*", omit_empty=TRUE))
#[1] "7"  "8"  "12" "11"
unlist(stri_split_fixed(v, ".", n=1, tokens_only=TRUE))
unlist(stri_split_regex(v, "[^\\w]", n=1, tokens_only=TRUE))
```

Other `sub` variations that use a capture group to target the leading characters specifically:

```
sub("(\\w+).+", "\\1", v) # \w matches [[:alnum:]_] (i.e. alphanumerics and underscores)
sub("([[:alnum:]]+).+", "\\1", v) # exclude underscores

# variations on a theme
sub("(\\w+)\\..*", "\\1", v)
sub("(\\d+)\\..*", "\\1", v) # narrower: \d for digits specifically
sub("(.+)\\..*", "\\1", v) # broader: "." matches any single character

# stringi variation just for fun:
stri_extract_first_regex(v, "\\w+")
```

Answer (score 3):

`scan()` would actually work well for this. Since we want everything before the first `.`, we can use that as a comment character and `scan()` will remove everything after and including that character, for each element in `v`.

```
scan(text = v, comment.char = ".")
# [1]  7  8 12 11
```

The above returns a numeric vector, which might be where you are headed.  If you need to stick with characters, add the `what` argument to denote we want a character vector returned.

```
scan(text = v, comment.char = ".", what = "")
# [1] "7"  "8"  "12" "11"
```

**Data:**

```
v <- c("7.7.4", "8", "12.6", "11.5.2.1")
```